# Can I customize the pointer size, color, etc. on the Windows 10 Home lock/logon screen?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, cursor

I'm running Windows 10 Home ver. 21H2. I've customized the pointer and cursor size and color for my user account. Can I do it for the lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

User mouse settings are configured in the Control Panel, and are per user.
They do not apply to the logon and the
lock screen, because there is then no current user account.

For these screens you need to change the settings inside the
"Default" user account. You can't login into this account,
so you need to do it via the registry.

Here is how to copy your mouse settings:

1. Run `regedit.exe` and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`
2. Right-click on `Mouse` key and select "Export" and select a file-name
   that ends with `.reg`
3. Open the exported file using `notepad`, replace `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`
   with `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` and save
4. For backup, in `regedit` navigate to
   `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Mouse` and Export its to a different
   backup file whose name also ends with `.reg`
5. Right-click the key `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Mouse` and select
   "Delete"
6. Exit `regedit`
7. Double-click the file from step 3 and allow it to execute
8. Repeat steps 1-7 for the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors`
9. Reboot.

(I have not tried this procedure, but it has a good chance of working.)

For a similar (but partial) method with screenshots, see the article
[Change mouse cursor speed at logon screen](https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/501-change-mouse-cursor-speed-at-logon-screen).

Comment: Thank you. I tried this (I hope accurately) and it didn't seem to change anything. Let me be very specific. I realize now that the only customization I actually want is that I have the "Windows Black (extra-large) (system scheme)" in my user account. I want that pointer on my lock screen. Is that possible? When I look at the REG_SZ entries in my current Mouse key, I don't see anything that would define this.

Comment: Please verify that the settings at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse` are the same as in `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Mouse`. Also that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors` is the same as `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Cursors`. If they are indeed identical, please add their screenshots to your post.